# On Android device ActionBar is not displayed for first and last tabs which are added dynamically

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-viewpager, fragment, fragmentpageradapter

When the Activity is instantiated for my Android App, a ViewPager and a FragmentPagerAdpter are also created.

Initially Fragment1 for Tab1 is created.  When onCreateView() is called for Fragment1, the ActionBar is also inflated and set to the current activity.  So far so good.  The display on Android device looks good.

When user press "Add" button on the ActionBar, Fragment2 for Tab2 is created as just described above. And I'm able to swipe back and forth between two tabs.  And the ActionBar shows up fine on either Tab1/2.

When a new Fragment is added, it is added to ArrayList, and FragmentPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() is called.  This allows the new Tab to be visible.

However after adding Fragment3 for Tab3, and when I swipe to it, the ActionBar does not show.  But Fragment3 for Tab3 is clearly visible.  When I swipe back to Fragment2, the ActionBar shows up.  When I swipe back to Fragment3, the ActionBar again disappears.

When I add Fragment4 for Tab4, and when I swipe to it, again the ActionBar disappears.  However now the ActionBar shows up for Fragment3 for Tab3 which was not the case when it was the last Fragment.

So when there are 3 or more Fragments which were added dynamically, the ActionBar does not show up for the last Fragment.  Also the ActonBar does not show up for the first Fragent either for this scenario.

After tracing the calls, onPause() method is called for the first or last Fragment when I swipe to it and the ActionBar is not displayed.  For the middle Fragments whose ActionBar shows up fine, onCreateView() method is called when I swipe to one of them.

I'm quite puzzled by the above inconsistent behavior relative to ActionBar display for Fragments.  I'm not sure why onPause() is called for the first/last Fragment which is current on display.  This seems to be culprit for not having the ActionBar being displayed.

Below are some code snippets:

```
public class MyApp extends Activity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    ....
            ViewPager viewPager;
            TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
            mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
            viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    ....
}

public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter 
    implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {

    public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }
   ....

public class MyFragment extends Fragment  implements {

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    .....
            View actionBarButtons =                       
                 inflater.inflate(R.layout.actionbar,
                 new LinearLayout(mActivity), false);
     ... add buttons here....
            mActivity.getActionBar().setCustomView(actionBarButtons);
    .....
}
```